# VirtualBox Login Loop and Moving Home Directory

Tags: command-line, virtualbox, login, home-directory

Truly hoping for some answers here, I'm at my wits end, but maybe this isn't the right forum.

I have been using Ubuntu through VirtualBox for a few weeks now. I found that I was having difficulty with lack of free space, so I (seemingly) successfully added a much larger partition.

The other day, I needed to build a docker image. It failed, due to lack of free space. I looked online to find ways to free up space, and found some commands as well as a suggestion to move my home directory to the new partition.

`sudo apt-get autoremove` and `sudo apt-get autoclean` both run but find nothing. `sudo apt-get clean` also returns nothing.

I do not seem to have any extra kernels lying around.

I was using the steps found here:
http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-hardware-18/how-can-i-move-my-home-directory-to-a-brand-new-hard-drive-625485/

It didn't seem to work. Now, I can no longer log in to my virtualbox - it loops me back to the login page after a few seconds. I can access the guest.

I've been looking at online resources  to fix this, and I'm at a loss. Running the shell (with <kbd>Ctrl+Alt+F3</kbd>).

`cat .Xsession-errors` appears to return nothing.

`df -h` shows that my main disk is at 100% usage, and the disk I added is at 1%.

I wanted to just go back and undo trying to move the Home directory - I have the original directory under a different name. However, now I can't remove or rename the current Home directly, it tells me that the `Device or Resource is busy`.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: you have to unmount the home partition before you can remove the directory. when you moved the home directory did you copy all files to the new partition including hidden ones? the partition should have /username/<your files and folders>  PS: the home partition has to automount at boot

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate the answer. I understand the idea of what I need to do, but I'm rather new to both VirtualBox and Linux so I'm not an expert at navigating controls yet. How would I automount it at boot? I believe I have it set up right in /etc/fstab, but perhaps it's something else

Comment: edit /etc/fstab -- and this line : UUID=<id of partition>  /home  ext4   defaults        0       2 .... if the files system isn't ext4 change as needed